# Running protractor from jbehave

Tags: angularjs, protractor, jbehave

Any leads on how to drive protractor cases from JBehave story files (instead of Cucumber as BDD)?

Answer (score 0):

Protractor has an API for different test frameworks.  Assuming JBehave isn't too radically different from the existing frameworks, you can probably adapt one or add a new framework: https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/master/lib/frameworks